# Spacing between divs

Tags: html, spacing

This is how my problem looks like:

[image: div spacings]

As you can see, there are 3 images (divs), and I wan't to remove that black spacings between each divs.

The most important thing is that, when I place in my css the following:

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Then it looks fine:

[image: Working example]

The problem is that I can't use `padding: 0` and `margin: 0` for my whole html, because other attributes will be broken then...

I've tried to add: `padding:0` and `margin:0` on each div (image), but it not work.

HTML Source:

```
<div id="sidebar-left" class="sidebar" role="complementary">
       <div class="sb-ui sb-title"><h3>Account</h3></div>
       <div class="sb-con">
            <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?subtopic=accountmanagement">My Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?subtopic=accountmanagement&action=logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="sb-ui sb-end"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#sidebar-left {
margin-right: 9px;
}

.sidebar {
width: 170px;
position: relative;
bottom: 7px;
}

.sidebar, #content {
float: left;
}

.sb-title {
height: 60px;
text-align: center;
}

.sb-ui {
background: url("../images/ui/sidebar_ui.png");
}

.sb-con {
background: url("../images/ui/sidebar_bgrepeat.jpg") repeat-y;
}

.sb-end {
height: 23px;
background-position: bottom center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sb-ui {
background: url("../images/ui/sidebar_ui.png");
}
```

All help attempts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's likely the margin on the `ul` is causing this.

```
.sb-con ul { padding:0; margin:0; }
```

may have the desired effect. The `li` might also be affecting the layout; but we can't tell from your provided code.

Your "catch all" reset removes the default margin/padding; hence why it looks ok.

Edit - your `.sb-title h3` may also need the bottom margin removed as it looks like you are using a fixed height (60px) but the default margin would add extra height.

This is easily debugged with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome's web inspector with the visual indications of where the spacing is coming from.

Comment: The margin on the `<ul>` and `<h3>`

Answer (score 1):

That's because of UL default margin.
You need style:

```
UL { margin: 0 }
```